# Write Dictionary which has Objects to file

Tags: c#, .net

I have such dictionary `Dictionary<string, object>`, dictionary holds string keys and objects as values. I need to save and later load such dictionary. What would be best method to do that?

Comment: http://www.dacris.com/blog/2010/07/31/c-serializable-dictionary-a-working-example/

Comment: I do not understand how to use that class. I create new SerializableDictionary<string, object>() object and how to save/load it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this serializable `Dictionary<TKey, TVal>`(tested):

http://www.dacris.com/blog/2010/07/31/c-serializable-dictionary-a-working-example/

```
Dictionary<String, Object> otherDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
otherDictionary.Add("Foo", new List<String>() { "1st Foo","2nd Foo","3rd Foo" });
var dict = new SerializableDictionary<String, Object>(otherDictionary);
```

write it to a file:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("test.binary", FileMode.Create))
{
    IFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(fileStream, dict);
}
```

read it from a file:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("test.binary", FileMode.Open))
{
    IFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    dict = (SerializableDictionary<String, Object>)bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

Note: Of course you don't need to create a second `Dictionary`. You can use the `SerializableDictionary` at the first place. That should just demonstrate how to use it with an already existing Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NewtonSoft Json.net: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx.
It is flexible and very friendly.

Answer (score 0):

How about serializing it to XML?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

```
object yourType = new Object();

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(yourType.GetType());

x.Serialize(Console.Out,yourType);
```

Comment: it doesn't seam to work. Throws a NotSupportedException during runtime

Comment: that means something in your type is not serializable, all child classes also need to be serializable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding in an extra dependency, you can use [protobuf.net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). This has the benefit of being fast (definitely faster than the XML serializer approach), and it works on the bog standard Dictionary.

Reference it in your assembly, then the following shows how to use it with a `MemoryStream`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dict[i] = i.ToString();
        }

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, dict);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var dict2 = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, string>>(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

So long as both the key and value type for the dictionary are serializable by protobuf.net, this will work.

EDIT:

If you want to use this approach, you have to make your key and value object's class serializable by ProtoBuf. In short, attach `[ProtoContract]` to the class, and attach e.g. `[ProtoMember(1)]` to each Property you want to be serialized. See the website for more details. Note both `string` and `int` are serializable out of the box.

Comment: I get error on object No serializer defined for type: System.Object

Comment: @Tomas: Using the protobuf serializer?

Comment: Yes, Protobuf do not know how to serialize Object.

Comment: @Tomas: What are you storing in the dictionary?

Comment: @Tomas: If you want to use this approach, you have to make your property value's class serializable by ProtoBuf. In short, attach `[ProtoContract]` to the class, and attach e.g. `[ProtoMember(1)]` to each Property you want to be serialized. See the website for more details.